# Azure DevOps REST API call retrieving only 100 records

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the below url for retrieving all the CouldTests, but it is returning only top 100 records. Is it possible to retrieve all the records?.

```
http://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=5.0
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

For more about the above Link please refer.:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is returning only top 100 records.

This is because

> On large collections, performance degrades when retrieving the later pages.

To avoid stress on the server, 100 is the default page size of REST api response which you can refer to [REST API Result limit](https://community.microfocus.com/t5/Quality-Center-ALM-User/Reg-REST-API-Result-limit/td-p/1016285).

> Is it possible to retrieve all the records?

Yes, as @Shayki Abramczyk said, the solution is to add a `top` parameter to select the top `n` records, make sure the `n` is bigger than the total amount of your all records.

For this solution, you can also check [Limited to 100 result TFS api](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4b1a288c-7a64-47e2-ad43-6de42fea4f96/limited-to-100-result-tfs-api?forum=tfsgeneral) and [Azure DevOps REST API: project count returned limited to 100](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/560373/azure-devops-rest-api-project-count-returned-limit.html).

Comment: Thank you. Could you please help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952258/azure-devops-rest-api-call-retrieving-only-top-100-records

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `$top` parameter in the URL:

```
http://{instance:/{collection}/{projects}/_apis/test/runs?api-versopn=5.0&$top=500
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer was not working for me. Probably they have changed the parameter name from $top, to searchCriteria.$top.

If that is not working, try this instead:
[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?searchCriteria.$top=1000&api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/git/repositories/%7BrepositoryId%7D/commits?searchCriteria.$top=1000&api-version=6.0)

Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0