# Azure DevOps REST API call retrieving only top 100 records

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the below API call for retrieving all the CouldTests, but it is returning only 100 records. How can retrieve all the records?.

***$uri = https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?minLastUpdatedDate=2020-01-28&maxLastUpdatedDate=2020-01-29&releaseIds=123456&$top=2000
$TestRuns = Invoke-RestMethod 
`-Uri $uri`

-Headers $headers***

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

For more about the above Link please refer.:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/query?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Invoke-WebRequest instead of Invoke-RestMethod and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

See the continuationToken portion of that doc link that you reference.  Basically, if the response contains a continuationToken, then you have to call the API again and pass in that continuationToken, repeating until there is no more continuationToken in the response.

This is common across most Azure APIs, although sometimes the naming is different such as nextLink.

Comment: Hi Kwill, I tried this, but the Continuous token returns null. So I am always getting only 100 records. Code is giving below.